# How to get total inserted row count from a table after bulk insert query mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, bulk

I am using a bulk insert query using php to insert into a mysql table. Here i want to know the total inserted records from this bulk insert query. After completion of the bulk insert i am using below code to get total inserted count.

```
//here bulk insert complete.Next i am calling this
$row_cnt = mysql_query("SELECT ROW_COUNT()");
echo "Affected:rows:".$inbound_cnt = mysql_num_rows($row_cnt);
```

Here i am getting Affected:rows:1.And i want last insert id also from this bulk insert.

```
echo "current_id:". $current_id = mysql_insert_id();
I am getting '0' ;
```

How can i find total inserted count? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// my insert query
 $data4 = "";
    $inbound_csv_cnt = count($csv_array);
    for($i=0;$i<$inbound_csv_cnt;$i++)
    {
   $data4.="('".$csv_array[$i][0]."','".$csv_array[$i][1]."','".$csv_array[$i][2]."'),";
    }
    $data4 = substr($data4,0,-1);
    $ins_sql = "INSERT INTO whv_inbound_response(`whv_id`, `rqv_id`, `whv_type`) values $data4" ;
    $res = mysql_query($ins_sql);
```

Comment: _i want last insert id also from this bulk insert._ Where is the INSERT statement?

Comment: Can you add your bulk-insert functionality in your question? Just want to see how you are doing this so that answers given by users will be more close to what you are expecting...

Comment: Added bulk insert query

Answer (score 0):

You can get `total records` before insert with this

```
 SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table_name; // save output in $old
```

Then Insert your data and again count total records now as `$new`

Now find the difference

```
$total_inserted_record = $new-$old;
```

Answer (score 0):

While using loop, you can also set a counter to count the number of rows, even before insert. Also, to get last insert ID, for mysqli procedural you may use

```
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn_string);
```

You already have number of records being insert in $inbound_csv_cnt